# H264 used in video for audio stream

Tags: audio, video, h.264, mpeg-4

I've been reading on the h.264/MPEG4 (AVC) format/codec, and from what I understand, it's a codec for audiovisual content. I've downloaded a few HD videos and looked up the codec in VLC player. What I've notice is that the h.264 is used a lot as a video codec, but can it be used as an audio codec?

In the picture below you see the H264 being use in the video stream but not in the audio stream. Is it possible that a video would use the H264 codec for the audio stream?

[image]

Comment: This is not for SO. Anyway, h264 is a video compression format, it doesn't work for sound...

Comment: Its a video compression standard, nothing to do with audio - that's the responsibility of an audio stream/s in the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H.264 is video codec, it's covered by MPEG-4 Part 10 "Advanced Video Coding" and H.264 is ITU alias for the same spec.

MPEG-4 Part 14 is "MP4 file format" which is the format of the file you hooked up onto VLC. It's video part is H.264, and it's audio part is AAC as you can see on the screenshot.

AAC is the audio codec. It's covered by [MPEG-4 Part 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_3) spec.